# Saving changes when patching entities with the API

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-webapi, dynamics-365

I'm using IFrame and javascript to make a list in my solution. It list the associated entities with a simple "Enable" button to a custom property.

I'm able to use the API to send a PATCH to Dynamics so the value is updated. But is there a API call to save changes? It's not the current page entity that I've patched, its a child. So I cant use `Xrm.Page.data.save`, since that will only save the current entity, not the changed entity in the list (?).

When doing changes in Dynamics 365 you could use CTRL+S, or click the small save button in the down left corner. How do I do this for the entity in the list of my IFrame? Any clues?

UPDATE:

I know the reason why I get the "unsaved changes" when I enter the entity after PATCHing the entity with the API calls. 
In our entities we have business rules that listens when the variable is set it goes and sets another variable. This works fine when you are in the entity in the browser and afterwards save. But when you set this value outside of the entity the value itself is saved, but the business rule does not run and the other values are not set. 
So when you enter the entity the rule runs and the other variable is set based on the PATCHed value (if it was different). Therefore you get a unsaved change.

SO; is there a way with the API i can "refresh" the entity, making it run the rule?

Comment: In my experience, you don't need to, PATCH is immediately applied

Comment: Sure @Alex. But I've experiencing that if I patch and view the entity the browser states it has unsaved changes.

Comment: Please explain the complete scenario (what you're doing, What you see, what you expect, what happens)

Comment: Hey @Alex, I found the solution. Please read my UPDATE. Is there a way to "refresh" the entity, running all logic attached?